# How to exclude products by tag from woocommerce shop page?

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, tags

I want to remove certain products by their tag from woocommerce Shop page query. Anyone can tell me how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your functions.php

```
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

    $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );

    $tax_query[] = array(
           'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
           'field' => 'slug',
           'terms' => array( 'banana' ), // Don't display products with the tag "banana"
           'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    );

    $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );
```

Comment: And if you want to do this on an `WP_Query` use the `tax_query` argument: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters